# Record types with multiple constructors in haskell

Tags: haskell

Very often when I write something using Haskell I need records with multiple constructors.
E.g. I want to develop some kind of logic schemes modelling. I came up to such type:

```
data Block a = Binary {
      binOp  :: a -> a -> a
    , opName :: String
    , in1 :: String
    , in2 :: String
    , out :: String
} | Unary {
      unOp  :: a -> a
    , opName :: String
    , in_ :: String
    , out :: String
}
```

It describes two types of blocks: binary (like and, or etc.) and unary (like not). They contain core function, input and output signals.

Another example: type to describe console commands.

```
data Command = Command { info :: CommandInfo
                       , action :: Args -> Action () }
             | FileCommand { info :: CommandInfo
                           , fileAction :: F.File -> Args -> Action ()
                           , permissions :: F.Permissions}
```

FileCommand needs additional field - required permissions and its action accept file as a first parameter.

As I read and search topics, books etc. about Haskell, it seems that it is not common to use types with record syntax and many constructors simultaneously.

So the question: is this "pattern" is not haskell-way and why? And if it is so, how to avoid it?

P.S. Which from proposed layouts is better, or maybe there is more readable one? Because I can't find any examples and suggestions in other sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When things start getting complicated, divide and conquer. Create complex entities by composing from simpler ones, not by ramming all the functionality into a single place. This has proven to be the optimal approach to programming in general, not just in Haskell.

Both your examples can benefit from separation. E.g.

```
data Block a = BinaryBlock (Binary a) | UnaryBlock (Unary a)

data Binary a = Binary {
  ...
}
data Unary = Unary {
  ...
}
```

Now you have `Binary` and `Unary` separated and you're able to write dedicated functions for each of them in isolation. Those functions will be much simpler and easier to reason about and maintain.

You'll also be able to benefit from putting those types in separate modules, which will resolve the field names collision. The final API for `Block` will be about very simple pattern matches and forwarding to specialised functions of `Binary` and `Unary`.

This approach is scalable. No matter how complex your entities or problems are you're always free to add another level of decomposition.

Comment: This is certainly good advice for many situations, but I don't quite agree that _all_ multi-block types should be split up. When none of the constituent blocks have any use on their own, this is mostly extra type namespace pollution without real benefits.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I never said that all multi-block types should be split up. I said that it should be done "When things start getting complicated", and OP presented just that kind of examples.

Comment: Isn't it a little bit ugly to have such type as:

`data Command = SimpleCommand SimpleCommand' | FileCommand FileCommand'`
?
And all this repetition when create values of this type. And, as I understand correctly, I have to implement all accessor functions by myself.

Comment: @uv.nikita Yes, it is a bit ugly. But it's the shortcoming of the language, not the approach. You can alternatively use aliases over `Either` like so: `type Block = Either A (Either B (Either C D))`, or declare polymorphic types similar to `Either` for arities bigger than 2. And yes decomposition will result in a bit more typing, but you have to understand that it's not the typing that the programmer spends most of his time on, but reasoning about the code and maintaining it. Therefore a decluttered code as a result of this approach is most valuable.

Answer (score 9):

A bit of a problem with such types is that the accessor functions cease to be total, which is rather frowned upon these days, for good reasons. That may be why they're avoided in books.

IMO, multi-constructor records are in principle still fine, only it needs to be understood that the labels should **not** be used as accessor functions. But they can nevertheless be pretty useful, in particular with the `RecordWildCards` extension.

Such types are certainly found in a number of libraries. When the constructors are *hidden* you're most definitely fine.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend not using ADTs and record types at the same time, simply for the reason that `unOp (Binary (+) "+" "1" "2" "3")` type checks without warning with `-Wall`, but will crash your program.  It essentially circumvents the type system and I personally think that feature should be removed from GHC or you should have to make each constructor have the same fields.

What you're wanting is a sum type of two records.  This is perfectly achievable and much safer with `Either`, and requires about as much boilerplate since you'd have to write `isBinaryOp` and `isUnaryOp` functions anyway to mirror `isLeft` or `isRight`.  Additionally, `Either` has many functions and instances that make working with it easier, while your custom type does not.  Just define each constructor as its own type:

```
data BinaryOp a = BinaryOp
    { binOp :: a -> a -> a
    , opName :: String
    , in1 :: String
    , in2 :: String
    , out :: String
    }
data UnaryOp a = UnaryOp
    { unOp :: a -> a
    , opName :: String
    , in_ :: String
    , out :: String
    }

type Block a = Either (BinaryOp a) (UnaryOp a)

data Command' = Command
    { info :: CommandInfo
    , action :: Args -> Action ()
    }
data FileCommand = FileCommand
    { fileAction :: F.File -> Args -> Action ()
    , permissions :: F.Permissions
    }

type Command = Either Command' FileCommand
```

This isn't really much more code, and it's isomorphic to your original types while taking full advantage of the type system and available functions.  You can also easily write equivalent functions between the two:

```
-- Before
accessBinOp :: (Block a -> b) -> Block a -> Maybe b
accessBinOp f b@(BinaryOp _ _ _ _ _) = Just $ f b
accessBinOp f _ = Nothing

-- After
accessBinOp :: (BinaryOp a -> b) -> Block a -> Maybe b
accessBinOp f (Left b) = Just $ f b
accessBinOp f _ = Nothing

-- Usage of the before version
> accessBinOp in1 (BinaryOp (+) "+" "1" "2" "3")
Just "1"
> accessBinOp in_ (BinaryOp (+) "+" "1" "2" "3")
*** Exception: No match in record selector in_
-- Usage of the after version
> accessBinOp in1 (Left $ BinaryOp (+) "+" "1" "2" "3")
Just "1"
> accessBinOp in_ (Left $ BinaryOp (+) "+" "1" "2" "3")
Couldn't match type `UnaryOp a1` with `BinaryOp a0`
Expected type: BinaryOp a0 -> String
  Actual type: UnaryOp a1 -> String
...
```

So before, you get an exception if you use a nontotal function, but afterwards you only have total functions and can restrict your accessors so that the type system catches your errors for you, rather than the runtime.

One key difference is not `f` can be restricted to only working on

Comment: It would be nice if GHC simply had a warning whenever a multiconstructor record label is used _as an accessor function_.

Comment: Interesting approach, but what if there will be more than two types of something?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Are you suggesting that they should only be used with `RecordWildCards`? I think that would be acceptable, but it would be a bit awkward for beginners. I don't like the idea that enabling `RecordWildCards` is what enables ADT records (or them being that closely related). Rather, I think they should be highly discouraged because Haskell has every capability of handling this same structure but in a fully typesafe manner, whether it be through my example or Nikita's or another technique entirely. ADT records allow people to ignore the type system and write bad programs.

Comment: You're probably right. Personally, I really like `RecordWildCards` a lot, and I think it's also fairly intuitive for beginners, but OTOH hand it's not exactly a useful thing to use when explaing about ADTs.

Comment: @uv.nikita You could go with Nikita Volkov's suggestion and create an ADT with a constructor for each record, which would certainly keep the data types flatter, but the other route is nesting data types.  Another alternative is [GADTs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT), which can be used like record types just without accessor functions.  You can only pattern match on them to extract the fields.  This is safer, but a bit more tedious.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think it would probably be a better solution to add a `GADTWildCards` extension that in some form or fashion allows you to use the wildcard syntax that's so convenient, but only lets you pattern match on constructors instead of using the field names as accessor functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What do you think of [this mockup](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/48f1fe2a123f5b93512c) for GADTs with labels?  Ideally the labels would _not_ be functions, but simply labels that GHC can insert as local bindings in wildcard expansion patterns.  It gives all the convenience of record ADTs and record wildcards without sacrificing type safety.  Keep in mind this is just a mockup, it's very possible I've missed something.

Comment: @bheklilr: I wasn't aware that GADT-record labels were treated different from ADT-record labels. Also, the syntax you use in that Gist (with `Cstr { ... } :: ...` instead of `Cstr :: { ... } -> ...`) is deprecated, isn't it? But the idea seems quite nice.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I wasn't aware that this already existed, has someone had this idea before me?  After a quick google search, it seems that I'm late to the game, I didn't realize GADTs could use record syntax already

Answer (score 4):

I think the partiality of the accessor functions is a major drawback. However, that's only the case when we're not using `lens`. With it it's a lot more cozy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Block a = ...

makeLenses ''Block
makePrisms ''Block
```

Partiality is now wholly remedied: the generated accessors are explicitly partial or total (in other words, 1-target lenses or 0-many-target traversals):

```
block1 = Binary (+) "a" "b" "c" "d"
block2 = Unary id "a" "b" "x"

main = do
    print $ block1^. opName -- total accessor
    print $ block2^? in2    -- partial accessor, prints Nothing
```

And we get all the other `lens` goodies of course.

Also, a problem with splitting out variants is that common field names will collide. With lenses we could have long non-colliding field names, and then use simple lens names overloaded via typeclasses, or `makeClassy` and `makeFields` from the lens library, but that's rather an increase in the "weight" of our solution.