# Alternative to algebraic data type with lots of constructors in record syntax

Tags: haskell, record, algebraic-data-types

I have a custom data type to contain elements of a landscape (cloud, sun, mountain, etc). I need to have a list of them, so I can't use different types and a common typeclass.

They share most of the fields in the constructor, however some have properties that other don't (for example, if the cloud is raining or not).

As of now, I have one data type with different constructors:

```
data Element = Sun {
  elemColorStart :: Color,
  elemColorEnd :: Color,
  elemCoords :: Coords,
  elemPeriod :: Float,
  elemSize :: Float,
  elemSteps :: Step,
  elemTime :: Float
}
| Cloud {
  elemKind :: CloudKind,
  elemColorMain :: Color,
  elemCoords :: Coords,
  elemRans :: [Float],
  elemSize' :: Size',
  elemSteps :: Step,
  elemTime :: Float
}
... etc
```

Alternatively I could have a common constructor with all the possible properties, and just not initialise them if theyre not needed, though this looks even worse.

This does not look very "Haskelly", and in fact this approach in general is quite object oriented. **What am I doing wrong?** Any other possible approach would be welcome; it is not an assignment so I don't really have any constraints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isolate the things into their own datatypes and have `Element` be a sum of them:

```
data Sun = Sun {
  colorStart :: Color,
  colorEnd :: Color,
  coords :: Coords,
  period :: Float,
  size :: Float,
  steps :: Step,
  time :: Float
}

data Cloud = Cloud {
  kind :: CloudKind,
  colorMain :: Color,
  coords :: Coords,
  rans :: [Float],
  size :: Size',
  steps :: Step,
  time :: Float
}

data Element = SunElement Sun | CloudElement Cloud
```

Now you can have dedicated APIs for things in isolation as much as all the good things that come with separation of concerns.

Oh and BTW, I've dropped the prefixes on field names, since now we have the `DuplicateRecordFields` extension.

BTW, you'll find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23955613/485115) useful.

Comment: Great answer, I would've never thought of it. However the prefixes are there because I didn't want to pollute the global namespace with things like `size` or `time` which I'll probably need for something else. Any simple solution for this?

Comment: @Lorenzo If you don't want to pollute the namespace, you either need prefixes (as you did) or to define them in a separate module and then `import qualified MyModule as M` and then use `M.field`. The latter is not terribly convenient, I think it's OK if one has a lot of types to add in the module.

Comment: I'd make the sum type's constructors strict. If the type is really performance critical, you might want to use `{-# UNPACK #-}`.

Comment: What about introducing support by `data Shared = Shared {
    steps :: Step,
  time :: Float,
coords :: Coords}`?

Comment: @dfeuer I tried to look it up but don't seem to fully understand the benefits. Also one of the records is an infinite list so that can't be strict?

Comment: @Lorenzo, making it strict: `data Element = SunElement !Sun | CloudElement !Cloud`. That means that to produce an `Element` you need to have a `Sun` or `Cloud`, rather than just a thunk that will evaluate one. The semantics are then identical to your original type, rather than lazier, and you're less likely to leak memory. Unpacking: `data Element = SunElement {-# UNPACK #-} !Sun | CloudElement {-# UNPACK #-} !Cloud`. This unpacks the record into the sum type constructor, instead of having a pointer to it. This is exactly the same, operationally, as your original version. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Unless you're extracting the records and storing them, unpacking will likely improve efficiency a bit by reducing allocation and avoiding indirection. But you probably don't need to worry about it unless performance is critical.

Comment: I'm not sure if the reference to `DuplicateRecordFields` is super helpful, given that there's no convenient way to actually _use_ both field names in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

A twist on Nikita's answer is to use an ADT called `Shared` holding fields found in both `Sun` and `Cloud`. If you want you can compare this to inheritance from OO.

```
data Shared = Shared {       
  coords :: Coords,     
  steps :: Step,
  time :: Float
}

data Sun = Sun {
  colorStart :: Color,
  colorEnd :: Color,
  period :: Float,
  size :: Float,
  shared :: Shared
}

data Cloud = Cloud {
  kind :: CloudKind,
  colorMain :: Color, 
  rans :: [Float],
  size :: Size',
  shared :: Shared
}

data Element = SunElement Sun | CloudElement Cloud
```